# How to efficiently parse fixed width files?

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to find an efficient way of parsing files that holds fixed width lines. For example, the first 20 characters represent a column, from 21:30 another one and so on.

Assuming that the line holds 100 characters, what would be an efficient way to parse a line into several components?

I could use string slicing per line, but it's a little bit ugly if the line is big. Are there any other fast methods?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Using the Python standard library's [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module would be fairly easy as well as fairly fast since it's written in C. The code below how it use it. It also allows columns of characters to be skipped by specifying negative values for the number of characters in the field.

```
import struct

fieldwidths = (2, -10, 24)
fmtstring = ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 'x' if fw < 0 else 's') for fw in fieldwidths)

# Convert Unicode input to bytes and the result back to Unicode string.
unpack = struct.Struct(fmtstring).unpack_from  # Alias.
parse = lambda line: tuple(s.decode() for s in unpack(line.encode()))

print('fmtstring: {!r}, record size: {} chars'.format(fmtstring, struct.calcsize(fmtstring)))

line = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789\n'
fields = parse(line)
print('fields: {}'.format(fields))
```

Output:

```
fmtstring: '2s 10x 24s', recsize: 36 chars
fields: ('AB', 'MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
```

Here's a way to do it with string slices, as you were considering but were concerned that it might get too ugly. It *is* kind of complicated and speedwise it's about the same as the version based the `struct` module — although I have an idea about how it could be sped up (which might make the extra complexity worthwhile). See update below on that topic.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from itertools import accumulate

def make_parser(fieldwidths):
    cuts = tuple(cut for cut in accumulate(abs(fw) for fw in fieldwidths))
    pads = tuple(fw < 0 for fw in fieldwidths) # bool values for padding fields
    flds = tuple(zip_longest(pads, (0,)+cuts, cuts))[:-1]  # ignore final one
    parse = lambda line: tuple(line[i:j] for pad, i, j in flds if not pad)
    # Optional informational function attributes.
    parse.size = sum(abs(fw) for fw in fieldwidths)
    parse.fmtstring = ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 'x' if fw < 0 else 's')
                                                for fw in fieldwidths)
    return parse

line = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789\n'
fieldwidths = (2, -10, 24)  # negative widths represent ignored padding fields
parse = make_parser(fieldwidths)
fields = parse(line)
print('format: {!r}, rec size: {} chars'.format(parse.fmtstring, parse.size))
print('fields: {}'.format(fields))
```

Output:

```
format: '2s 10x 24s', rec size: 36 chars
fields: ('AB', 'MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
```

##### Update

As I suspected, there *is* a way of making the string-slicing version of the code faster — which in Python 2.7 make it about the same speed as the version using `struct`, but in Python 3.x make it 233% faster (as well as the un-optimized version of itself which is about the same speed as the `struct` version).

What the version presented above does is define a lambda function that's primarily a comprehension that generates the limits of a bunch of slices at runtime.

```
parse = lambda line: tuple(line[i:j] for pad, i, j in flds if not pad)
```

Which is equivalent to a statement like the following, depending on the values of `i` and `j` in the `for` loop, to something looking like this:

```
parse = lambda line: tuple(line[0:2], line[12:36], line[36:51], ...)
```

However the latter executes more than twice as fast since the slice boundaries are all constants.

Fortunately it relatively easy to convert and "compile" the former into the latter using the built-in `eval()` function:

```
def make_parser(fieldwidths):
    cuts = tuple(cut for cut in accumulate(abs(fw) for fw in fieldwidths))
    pads = tuple(fw < 0 for fw in fieldwidths) # bool flags for padding fields
    flds = tuple(zip_longest(pads, (0,)+cuts, cuts))[:-1]  # ignore final one
    slcs = ', '.join('line[{}:{}]'.format(i, j) for pad, i, j in flds if not pad)
    parse = eval('lambda line: ({})\n'.format(slcs))  # Create and compile source code.
    # Optional informational function attributes.
    parse.size = sum(abs(fw) for fw in fieldwidths)
    parse.fmtstring = ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 'x' if fw < 0 else 's')
                                                for fw in fieldwidths)
    return parse
```

Comment: +1 that's nice. In a way, I think this is similar to my approach (at least when you're getting the results), but obviously way faster.

Comment: How would that work with unicode? Or, a utf-8 encoded string? `struct.unpack` seems to operate on binary data. I can't get this working.

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke: The struct module is *designed* to operate on binary data. Files with fixed-width fields are legacy jobs which are also highly likely to pre-date UTF-8 (in mind set, if not in chronology). Bytes read from files are binary data. You don't have unicode in files. You need to decode bytes to get unicode.

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke: Clarification: In those legacy file formats, each field is a fixed number of *bytes*, not a fixed number of characters. Although unlikely to be encoded in UTF-8, they can be encoded in an encoding that has a variable number of bytes per character e.g. gbk, big5, euc-jp, shift-jis, etc. If you wish to work in unicode, you can't decode the whole record at once; you need to decode each field.

Comment: @John Machin Thank you, I understood what you meant. For some reason I haven't seen this as an approach to legacy file formats, hence me asking about multibyte characters. (And yeah, thinking of unicode was dumb)

Comment: also, something that threw me off, the `fieldwidths` are the width of each extracted section of the string and have to add up to the total length of the string, they aren't necessarily the index at which the parsed string will be sliced. `(2,10,24)` won't get you `('AB','CDEFGHIJ','KLMNOPQRSTUVWX','YZ0123456789')`

Comment: @dnfehren: Exactly. That's part of why I separated them out and gave them the descriptive name `fieldwidths` (rather than just putting a tuple literal in the generator expression used in the `join()` call). They don't have to add up to the total length of the string, just at least that much (this is illustrated in the example, where the trailing `\n` gets ignored).

Comment: Interesting, seems much faster than using slices. But what if we do not need all fields, let's say we want to extract only ('AB', 'MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'). Is there a way to specify this in the fmtstring? Thx

Comment: @Mannaggia: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes, the struct module has the `'x'` format character for pad bytes. So if the `fmtstring` had been `'2s 10x 24s'` with the test line, the result would have been just `('AB', 'MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')`. In fact I think this would be a good enhancement and have added the feature to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke: Just reread your comment from long ago about using the `struct` module approach for utf-8 encoded strings and wanted to alert you to the fact that Update 1 addresses that (although it was done for Python 3 compatibility).

Comment: This breaks down entirely when you try to apply this for Unicode values (like in Python 3) with text outside the ASCII character set and where 'fixed width' means 'fixed number of *characters*', not bytes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think Update #2 handles Unicode values just fine in Python 3 (using character field widths).

Comment: @martineau: thanks for updating! Yes, using slice should make this work with field widths based on codepoints rather than bytes. :-)

Comment: @martineau this answer needs to be fixed for UTF8. People are copying the first snippet blindly and running into problems. The UTF8 solution should be moved to the top and clearly marked as a UTF8 solution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm not sure what "this" you want to draw attention to. Anyhow, this is a very old answer, which I have updated over the years, but regardless, anyone reading it should know the necessity of reading it to the very end.

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73126970/dealing-with-non-ascii-characters-when-parsing-fixed-width-txt-file/73133685) question the first snippet was copied and used to parse UTF8 files. Yes, the OP should have read the entire answer but (too) many times people just copy the first snippet of the first answer that seems to work. Especially if that snippet is part of an upvoted answer

Comment: @martineau unfortunately, that's how copy-pasta works. If people aren't willing to read the entire answer, at least we can put the "short" version on top and hope they use that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Sorry, I'm not going to optimize my 11 year old answer to suit your answer (or folks in too much of a hurry to read the whole thing).

Comment: @martineau I didn't criticize your answer. I even upvoted it. I pointed out a way it can be improved even when people are too lazy - or confuse UTF8 for some kind of escape sequence. I've done the same for my answers in similar situations: put a "Short Version" at the top with just the code and a 1 line explanation and a `Long Version` section explaining what's going on.

Comment: @martineau you're right after all. Turns out that OP doesn't understand what UTF8 is and won't be persuaded even after seeing actual results

Answer (score 75):

I'm not really sure if this is efficient, but it should be readable (as opposed to do the slicing manually). I defined a function `slices` that gets a string and column lengths, and returns the substrings. I made it a generator, so for really long lines, it doesn't build a temporary list of substrings.

```
def slices(s, *args):
    position = 0
    for length in args:
        yield s[position:position + length]
        position += length
```

Example

```
In [32]: list(slices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 2))
Out[32]: ['ab']

In [33]: list(slices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 2, 10, 50))
Out[33]: ['ab', 'cdefghijkl', 'mnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789']

In [51]: d,c,h = slices('dogcathouse', 3, 3, 5)
In [52]: d,c,h
Out[52]: ('dog', 'cat', 'house')
```

But I think the advantage of a generator is lost if you need all columns at once. Where one could benefit from is when you want to process columns one by one, say in a loop.

Comment: AFAICT, this method is slower than `struct`, but it is readable and easier to handle. I've done some tests using your `slices function`, `struct` module and also `re` module and it turns out for large files, `struct` is the fastest, `re` comes second (1.5x slower) and `slices` third (2x slower). There is however a small overhead using `struct` so your `slices function` can be faster on smaller files.

Answer (score 34):

Two more options that are easier and prettier than already mentioned solutions:

The first is using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'filename.txt'

#inferred - as suggested in the comments by James Paul Mason
data = pd.read_fwf(path, colspecs='infer')

# Or using Pandas with a column specification
col_specification = [(0, 20), (21, 30), (31, 50), (51, 100)]
data = pd.read_fwf(path, colspecs=col_specification)
```

And the second option using numpy.loadtxt:

```
import numpy as np

# Using NumPy and letting it figure it out automagically
data_also = np.loadtxt(path)
```

It really depends on in what way you want to use your data.

Comment: Is this competitive with the accepted answer in terms of speed?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but it should be a lot faster than the accepted answer.

Comment: Pandas can do automagic detection on its own if you set ```colspecs='infer'``` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: Thanks, don't think that was an option when I wrote the answer, will update it with that.

Comment: The question doesn't specify an efficiency metric, and this answer is certainly the most efficient in terms of *human* processing, i.e., readability and code complexity.

Answer (score 15):

The code below gives a sketch of what you might want to do if you have some serious fixed-column-width file handling to do.

"Serious" = multiple record types in each of multiple file types, records up to 1000 bytes, the layout-definer and "opposing" producer/consumer is a government department with attitude, layout changes result in unused columns, up to a million records in a file, ...

Features: Precompiles the struct formats. Ignores unwanted columns. Converts input strings to required data types (sketch omits error handling). Converts records to object instances (or dicts, or named tuples if you prefer).

Code:

```
import struct, datetime, io, pprint

# functions for converting input fields to usable data
cnv_text = rstrip
cnv_int = int
cnv_date_dmy = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d%m%Y") # ddmmyyyy
# etc

# field specs (field name, start pos (1-relative), len, converter func)
fieldspecs = [
    ('surname', 11, 20, cnv_text),
    ('given_names', 31, 20, cnv_text),
    ('birth_date', 51, 8, cnv_date_dmy),
    ('start_date', 71, 8, cnv_date_dmy),
    ]

fieldspecs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) # just in case

# build the format for struct.unpack
unpack_len = 0
unpack_fmt = ""
for fieldspec in fieldspecs:
    start = fieldspec[1] - 1
    end = start + fieldspec[2]
    if start > unpack_len:
        unpack_fmt += str(start - unpack_len) + "x"
    unpack_fmt += str(end - start) + "s"
    unpack_len = end
field_indices = range(len(fieldspecs))
print unpack_len, unpack_fmt
unpacker = struct.Struct(unpack_fmt).unpack_from

class Record(object):
    pass
    # or use named tuples

raw_data = """\
....v....1....v....2....v....3....v....4....v....5....v....6....v....7....v....8
          Featherstonehaugh   Algernon Marmaduke  31121969            01012005XX
"""

f = cStringIO.StringIO(raw_data)
headings = f.next()
for line in f:
    # The guts of this loop would of course be hidden away in a function/method
    # and could be made less ugly
    raw_fields = unpacker(line)
    r = Record()
    for x in field_indices:
        setattr(r, fieldspecs[x][0], fieldspecs[x][3](raw_fields[x]))
    pprint.pprint(r.__dict__)
    print "Customer name:", r.given_names, r.surname
```

Output:

```
78 10x20s20s8s12x8s
{'birth_date': datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 0, 0),
 'given_names': 'Algernon Marmaduke',
 'start_date': datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 'surname': 'Featherstonehaugh'}
Customer name: Algernon Marmaduke Featherstonehaugh
```

Comment: How would one update this code to parse records greater than 1000 bytes? I'm running into this error: `struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 1157 bytes`

Answer (score 4):

```
> str = '1234567890'
> w = [0,2,5,7,10]
> [ str[ w[i-1] : w[i] ] for i in range(1,len(w)) ]
['12', '345', '67', '890']
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved with a dictionary that contains where fields start and end. Giving start and end points helped me to manage changes at the length of the column also.

```py
# fixed length
#      '---------- ------- ----------- -----------'
line = '20.06.2019 myname  active      mydevice   '
SLICES = {'date_start': 0,
         'date_end': 10,
         'name_start': 11,
         'name_end': 18,
         'status_start': 19,
         'status_end': 30,
         'device_start': 31,
         'device_end': 42}

def get_values_as_dict(line, SLICES):
    values = {}
    key_list = {key.split("_")[0] for key in SLICES.keys()}
    for key in key_list:
       values[key] = line[SLICES[key+"_start"]:SLICES[key+"_end"]].strip()
    return values

>>> print (get_values_as_dict(line,SLICES))
{'status': 'active', 'name': 'myname', 'date': '20.06.2019', 'device': 'mydevice'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple module for Python 3, based on [John Machin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916375/243392) - adapt as needed :)

```
"""
fixedwidth

Parse and iterate through a fixedwidth text file, returning record objects.

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916375/243392


USAGE

    import fixedwidth, pprint

    # define the fixed width fields we want
    # fieldspecs is a list of [name, description, start, width, type] arrays.
    fieldspecs = [
        ["FILEID", "File Identification", 1, 6, "A/N"],
        ["STUSAB", "State/U.S. Abbreviation (USPS)", 7, 2, "A"],
        ["SUMLEV", "Summary Level", 9, 3, "A/N"],
        ["LOGRECNO", "Logical Record Number", 19, 7, "N"],
        ["POP100", "Population Count (100%)", 30, 9, "N"],
    ]

    # define the fieldtype conversion functions
    fieldtype_fns = {
        'A': str.rstrip,
        'A/N': str.rstrip,
        'N': int,
    }

    # iterate over record objects in the file
    with open(f, 'rb'):
        for record in fixedwidth.reader(f, fieldspecs, fieldtype_fns):
            pprint.pprint(record.__dict__)

    # output:
    {'FILEID': 'SF1ST', 'LOGRECNO': 2, 'POP100': 1, 'STUSAB': 'TX', 'SUMLEV': '040'}
    {'FILEID': 'SF1ST', 'LOGRECNO': 3, 'POP100': 2, 'STUSAB': 'TX', 'SUMLEV': '040'}    
    ...

"""

import struct, io


# fieldspec columns
iName, iDescription, iStart, iWidth, iType = range(5)


def get_struct_unpacker(fieldspecs):
    """
    Build the format string for struct.unpack to use, based on the fieldspecs.
    fieldspecs is a list of [name, description, start, width, type] arrays.
    Returns a string like "6s2s3s7x7s4x9s".
    """
    unpack_len = 0
    unpack_fmt = ""
    for fieldspec in fieldspecs:
        start = fieldspec[iStart] - 1
        end = start + fieldspec[iWidth]
        if start > unpack_len:
            unpack_fmt += str(start - unpack_len) + "x"
        unpack_fmt += str(end - start) + "s"
        unpack_len = end
    struct_unpacker = struct.Struct(unpack_fmt).unpack_from
    return struct_unpacker


class Record(object):
    pass
    # or use named tuples


def reader(f, fieldspecs, fieldtype_fns):
    """
    Wrap a fixedwidth file and return records according to the given fieldspecs.
    fieldspecs is a list of [name, description, start, width, type] arrays.
    fieldtype_fns is a dictionary of functions used to transform the raw string values, 
    one for each type.
    """

    # make sure fieldspecs are sorted properly
    fieldspecs.sort(key=lambda fieldspec: fieldspec[iStart])

    struct_unpacker = get_struct_unpacker(fieldspecs)

    field_indices = range(len(fieldspecs))

    for line in f:
        raw_fields = struct_unpacker(line) # split line into field values
        record = Record()
        for i in field_indices:
            fieldspec = fieldspecs[i]
            fieldname = fieldspec[iName]
            s = raw_fields[i].decode() # convert raw bytes to a string
            fn = fieldtype_fns[fieldspec[iType]] # get conversion function
            value = fn(s) # convert string to value (eg to an int)
            setattr(record, fieldname, value)
        yield record


if __name__=='__main__':

    # test module

    import pprint, io

    # define the fields we want
    # fieldspecs are [name, description, start, width, type]
    fieldspecs = [
        ["FILEID", "File Identification", 1, 6, "A/N"],
        ["STUSAB", "State/U.S. Abbreviation (USPS)", 7, 2, "A"],
        ["SUMLEV", "Summary Level", 9, 3, "A/N"],
        ["LOGRECNO", "Logical Record Number", 19, 7, "N"],
        ["POP100", "Population Count (100%)", 30, 9, "N"],
    ]

    # define a conversion function for integers
    def to_int(s):
        """
        Convert a numeric string to an integer.
        Allows a leading ! as an indicator of missing or uncertain data.
        Returns None if no data.
        """
        try:
            return int(s)
        except:
            try:
                return int(s[1:]) # ignore a leading !
            except:
                return None # assume has a leading ! and no value

    # define the conversion fns
    fieldtype_fns = {
        'A': str.rstrip,
        'A/N': str.rstrip,
        'N': to_int,
        # 'N': int,
        # 'D': lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d%m%Y"), # ddmmyyyy
        # etc
    }

    # define a fixedwidth sample
    sample = """\
SF1ST TX04089000  00000023748        1 
SF1ST TX04090000  00000033748!       2
SF1ST TX04091000  00000043748!        
"""
    sample_data = sample.encode() # convert string to bytes
    file_like = io.BytesIO(sample_data) # create a file-like wrapper around bytes

    # iterate over record objects in the file
    for record in reader(file_like, fieldspecs, fieldtype_fns):
        # print(record)
        pprint.pprint(record.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what NumPy uses under the hood (much much simplified, but still - this code is found in the `LineSplitter class` within the `_iotools module`):

```
import numpy as np

DELIMITER = (20, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20)

idx = np.cumsum([0] + list(DELIMITER))
slices = [slice(i, j) for (i, j) in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:])]

def parse(line):
    return [line[s] for s in slices]
```

It does not handle negative delimiters for ignoring column so it is not as versatile as `struct`, but it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Because my old work often handles 1 million lines of fixwidth data, I did research on this issue when I started using Python.

There are 2 types of FixedWidth

1. ASCII FixedWidth (ascii character length = 1, double-byte encoded character length = 2)
2. Unicode FixedWidth (ascii character & double-byte encoded character length = 1)

If the resource string is all composed of ascii characters, then ASCII FixedWidth = Unicode FixedWidth

Fortunately, string and byte are different in py3, which reduces a lot of confusion when dealing with double-byte encoded characters (e.g.gbk, big5, euc-jp, shift-jis, etc.).
For the processing of "ASCII FixedWidth", the String is usually converted to Bytes and then split.

Without importing third-party modules
totalLineCount = 1 million, lineLength = 800 byte , FixedWidthArgs=(10,25,4,....), I split the Line in about 5 ways and get the following conclusion:

1. struct is the fastest (1x)
2. Loop only, not pre-processing FixedWidthArgs is the slowest (5x+)
3. `slice(bytes)` is faster than `slice(string)`
4. The source string is the bytes test result: struct(1x) , operator.itemgetter(1.7x) , precompiled sliceObject & list comprehensions(2.8x), re.patten object (2.9x)

When dealing with large files, we often use `with open ( file, "rb") as f:`.
The method traverses one of the above files, about 2.4 second.
I think the appropriate handler, which processes 1 million rows of data, splits each row into 20 fields and takes less than 2.4 seconds.

**I only find that `stuct` and `itemgetter` meet the requirements**

ps:  For normal display, I converted unicode str to bytes.
If you are in a double-byte environment, you don't need to do this.

```py
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import itemgetter

def oprt_parser(sArgs):
    sum_arg = tuple(accumulate(abs(i) for i in sArgs))
    # Negative parameter field index
    cuts = tuple(i for i,num in enumerate(sArgs) if num < 0)
    # Get slice args and Ignore fields of negative length
    ig_Args = tuple(item for i, item in enumerate(zip((0,)+sum_arg,sum_arg)) if i not in cuts)
    # Generate `operator.itemgetter` object
    oprtObj =itemgetter(*[slice(s,e) for s,e in ig_Args])
    return oprtObj

lineb = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\xb0\xa1\xb2\xbb\xb4\xd3\xb5\xc4\xb6\xee\xb7\xa2\xb8\xf6\xba\xcd0123456789'
line = lineb.decode("GBK")

# Unicode Fixed Width
fieldwidthsU = (13, -13, 4, -4, 5,-5) # Negative width fields is ignored
# ASCII Fixed Width
fieldwidths = (13, -13, 8, -8, 5,-5) # Negative width fields is ignored
# Unicode FixedWidth processing
parse = oprt_parser(fieldwidthsU)
fields = parse(line)
print('Unicode FixedWidth','fields: {}'.format(tuple(map(lambda s: s.encode("GBK"), fields))))
# ASCII FixedWidth processing
parse = oprt_parser(fieldwidths)
fields = parse(lineb)
print('ASCII FixedWidth','fields: {}'.format(fields))
line = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789\n'
fieldwidths = (2, -10, 24)
parse = oprt_parser(fieldwidths)
fields = parse(line)
print(f"fields: {fields}")
```

Output:

```
Unicode FixedWidth fields: (b'abcdefghijklm', b'\xb0\xa1\xb2\xbb\xb4\xd3\xb5\xc4', b'01234')
ASCII FixedWidth fields: (b'abcdefghijklm', b'\xb0\xa1\xb2\xbb\xb4\xd3\xb5\xc4', b'01234')
fields: ('AB', 'MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
```

**`oprt_parser` is 4x `make_parser`(list comprehensions + slice)**

---

During the research, it was found that when the cpu speed is faster, it seems that the efficiency of the `re` method increases faster.
Since I don't have more and better computers to test, provide my test code, if anyone is interested, you can test it with a faster computer.

Run Environment:

- os:win10
- python: 3.7.2
- CPU:amd athlon x3 450
- HD:seagate 1T

```py
import timeit
import time
import re
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import itemgetter

def eff2(stmt,onlyNum= False,showResult=False):
    '''test function'''
    if onlyNum:
        rl = timeit.repeat(stmt=stmt,repeat=roundI,number=timesI,globals=globals())
        avg = sum(rl) / len(rl)
        return f"{avg * (10 ** 6)/timesI:0.4f}"
    else:
        rl = timeit.repeat(stmt=stmt,repeat=10,number=1000,globals=globals())
        avg = sum(rl) / len(rl)
        print(f"【{stmt}】")
        print(f"\tquick avg = {avg * (10 ** 6)/1000:0.4f} s/million")
        if showResult:
            print(f"\t  Result = {eval(stmt)}\n\t  timelist = {rl}\n")
        else:
            print("")

def upDouble(argList,argRate):
    return [c*argRate for c in argList]

tbStr = "000000001111000002222真2233333333000000004444444QAZ55555555000000006666666ABC这些事中文字abcdefghijk"
tbBytes = tbStr.encode("GBK")
a20 = (4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2, 2 ,2,8,8,7,3,8,8,7,3, 12 ,11)
a20U = (4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2, 1 ,2,8,8,7,3,8,8,7,3, 6 ,11)
Slng = 800
rateS = Slng // 100

tStr = "".join(upDouble(tbStr , rateS))
tBytes = tStr.encode("GBK")
spltArgs = upDouble( a20 , rateS)
spltArgsU = upDouble( a20U , rateS)

testList = []
timesI = 100000
roundI = 5
print(f"test round = {roundI} timesI = {timesI} sourceLng = {len(tStr)} argFieldCount = {len(spltArgs)}")


print(f"pure str \n{''.ljust(60,'-')}")
# ==========================================
def str_parser(sArgs):
    def prsr(oStr):
        r = []
        r_ap = r.append
        stt=0
        for lng in sArgs:
            end = stt + lng 
            r_ap(oStr[stt:end])
            stt = end 
        return tuple(r)
    return prsr

Str_P = str_parser(spltArgsU)
# eff2("Str_P(tStr)")
testList.append("Str_P(tStr)")

print(f"pure bytes \n{''.ljust(60,'-')}")
# ==========================================
def byte_parser(sArgs):
    def prsr(oBytes):
        r, stt = [], 0
        r_ap = r.append
        for lng in sArgs:
            end = stt + lng
            r_ap(oBytes[stt:end])
            stt = end
        return r
    return prsr
Byte_P = byte_parser(spltArgs)
# eff2("Byte_P(tBytes)")
testList.append("Byte_P(tBytes)")

# re,bytes
print(f"re compile object \n{''.ljust(60,'-')}")
# ==========================================


def rebc_parser(sArgs,otype="b"):
    re_Args = "".join([f"(.{{{n}}})" for n in sArgs])
    if otype == "b":
        rebc_Args = re.compile(re_Args.encode("GBK"))
    else:
        rebc_Args = re.compile(re_Args)
    def prsr(oBS):
        return rebc_Args.match(oBS).groups()
    return prsr
Rebc_P = rebc_parser(spltArgs)
# eff2("Rebc_P(tBytes)")
testList.append("Rebc_P(tBytes)")

Rebc_Ps = rebc_parser(spltArgsU,"s")
# eff2("Rebc_Ps(tStr)")
testList.append("Rebc_Ps(tStr)")


print(f"struct \n{''.ljust(60,'-')}")
# ==========================================

import struct
def struct_parser(sArgs):
    struct_Args = " ".join(map(lambda x: str(x) + "s", sArgs))
    def prsr(oBytes):
        return struct.unpack(struct_Args, oBytes)
    return prsr
Struct_P = struct_parser(spltArgs)
# eff2("Struct_P(tBytes)")
testList.append("Struct_P(tBytes)")

print(f"List Comprehensions + slice \n{''.ljust(60,'-')}")
# ==========================================
import itertools
def slice_parser(sArgs):
    tl = tuple(itertools.accumulate(sArgs))
    slice_Args = tuple(zip((0,)+tl,tl))
    def prsr(oBytes):
        return [oBytes[s:e] for s, e in slice_Args]
    return prsr
Slice_P = slice_parser(spltArgs)
# eff2("Slice_P(tBytes)")
testList.append("Slice_P(tBytes)")

def sliceObj_parser(sArgs):
    tl = tuple(itertools.accumulate(sArgs))
    tl2 = tuple(zip((0,)+tl,tl))
    sliceObj_Args = tuple(slice(s,e) for s,e in tl2)
    def prsr(oBytes):
        return [oBytes[so] for so in sliceObj_Args]
    return prsr
SliceObj_P = sliceObj_parser(spltArgs)
# eff2("SliceObj_P(tBytes)")
testList.append("SliceObj_P(tBytes)")

SliceObj_Ps = sliceObj_parser(spltArgsU)
# eff2("SliceObj_Ps(tStr)")
testList.append("SliceObj_Ps(tStr)")


print(f"operator.itemgetter + slice object \n{''.ljust(60,'-')}")
# ==========================================

def oprt_parser(sArgs):
    sum_arg = tuple(accumulate(abs(i) for i in sArgs))
    cuts = tuple(i for i,num in enumerate(sArgs) if num < 0)
    ig_Args = tuple(item for i,item in enumerate(zip((0,)+sum_arg,sum_arg)) if i not in cuts)
    oprtObj =itemgetter(*[slice(s,e) for s,e in ig_Args])
    return oprtObj

Oprt_P = oprt_parser(spltArgs)
# eff2("Oprt_P(tBytes)")
testList.append("Oprt_P(tBytes)")

Oprt_Ps = oprt_parser(spltArgsU)
# eff2("Oprt_Ps(tStr)")
testList.append("Oprt_Ps(tStr)")

print("|".join([s.split("(")[0].center(11," ") for s in testList]))
print("|".join(["".center(11,"-") for s in testList]))
print("|".join([eff2(s,True).rjust(11," ") for s in testList]))
```

Output:

```
Test round = 5 timesI = 100000 sourceLng = 744 argFieldCount = 20
...
...
   Str_P | Byte_P | Rebc_P | Rebc_Ps | Struct_P | Slice_P | SliceObj_P|SliceObj_Ps| Oprt_P | Oprt_Ps
-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-- ---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|---- -------|-----------
     9.6315| 7.5952| 4.4187| 5.6867| 1.5123| 5.2915| 4.2673| 5.7121| 2.4713| 3.9051
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters More efficient function

Answer (score 0):

String slicing doesn't have to be ugly as long as you keep it organized.  Consider storing your field widths in a dictionary and then using the associated names to create an object:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Entry:
    def __init__(self, line):

        name2width = OrderedDict()
        name2width['foo'] = 2
        name2width['bar'] = 3
        name2width['baz'] = 2

        pos = 0
        for name, width in name2width.items():

            val = line[pos : pos + width]
            if len(val) != width:
                raise ValueError("not enough characters: \'{}\'".format(line))

            setattr(self, name, val)
            pos += width

file = "ab789yz\ncd987wx\nef555uv"

entry = []

for line in file.split('\n'):
    entry.append(Entry(line))

print(entry[1].bar) # output: 987
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to process text files containing fixed width fields using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). More specifically, using [named capture groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups). It's fast, does not require importing large libraries and is quite descriptive and convenient (in my opinion).

I also like the fact that the named capture groups are basically auto-documenting the data format, acting as a sort of *data specification*, since each capture group can be written to define each fields' name, data type and length.

Here's simple example...

```py
import re

data = [
    "1234ABCDEFGHIJ5", 
    "6789KLMNOPQRST0"
]

record_regex = (
    r"^"
    r"(?P<firstnumbers>[0-9]{4})"
    r"(?P<middletext>[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\s]{10})"
    r"(?P<lastnumber>[0-9]{1})"
    r"$"
)

records = []

for line in data:
    match = re.match(record_regex, line)
    if match:
        records.append(match.groupdict())

print(records)
```

...that yields a convenient dictionary of each record:

```py
[
    {'firstnumbers': '1234', 'lastnumber': '5', 'middletext': 'ABCDEFGHIJ'},
    {'firstnumbers': '6789', 'lastnumber': '0', 'middletext': 'KLMNOPQRST'}
]
```

Helpful tools, like the [online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/), are available if you are not familiar (or comfortable) with Python regular expressions or named capture groups.