# Python library for parsing space delimited files

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient way of parsing fixed width files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/efficient-way-of-parsing-fixed-width-files-in-python)

Not even sure if "space delimited" is really the right term here (which is probably what is hindering my search efforts). Basically, field X begins at character 0 and field Y begins at character 30. Pretty sure this is an ancient file format that one of our systems still uses. I could roll my own solution easily, but I would rather use an existing library if one exists.

Comment: You're right, "space delimited" probably isn't the best term, because it could also mean a CSV dialect that uses spaces instead of commas… but your explanation makes it perfectly clear what you actually want, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question looks pretty similar to yours. It looks like they had some suggestions of which modules would be most useful:

[How to efficiently parse fixed width files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/efficient-way-of-parsing-fixed-width-files-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    x, y = line[:28], line[29:]
```

Should seperate the `x, y` arguments from each line.

Comment: That is really the best approach for a fixed width file, just split the strings at the appropriate places.

Comment: The `line.split()` here is going to break things. For example, with `'1234567890123456789012345     abcdef'`, it will set `line = [''1234567890123456789012345', 'abcdef']`, and then `line[:28]` will raise an index error. If you take the `split` line out, then this is the right answer.

Comment: @abarnert - Thanks, I read the question differently, meaning there are n amount of values, space delimited, and the first 30 are x, the rest are y.

Comment: +1 now that's fixed. But a few last comments: Many fixed-width formats allow the entire column to be used with no space at all, so `12345678901234567890123456abcdef` where the fields are `12345678901234567890123456` and `abcdef`. It doesn't sound like that's true in the OP's case, but in general, you probably want `line[:29], line[29:]` rather than `line[:28], line[29:]`. Also, you probably want `line[:29].rstrip()` to get rid of the excess spaces. And finally, why are you starting field `Y` at column 29 instead of the OP's 30?

Answer (score -1):

Subclass [csv.Dialect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) as follows:

```
import csv

class SpaceCsv(csv.Dialect):
    "csv format for exporting tables"
    delimiter = None
    doublequote = True
    escapechar = None
    lineterminator = '\n'
    quotechar = '"'
    skipinitialspace = True
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
csv.register_dialect('space', SpaceCsv)
```

Then use this as `csv.reader(filename, dialect="space")`. Let me know how you get on...

Comment: This will raise a `TypeError: delimiter must be set`. And, even if it worked, it's not going to split on fixed-width columns, which is what the OP asked for.