# Parse a variable row in python

Tags: python, linux, row

Coming from this link: [Splitlines in Python a table with empty spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252728/splitlines-in-python-a-table-with-empty-spaces)

It works well but there is a problem when the size of the columns change:

```
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
init          1       root  cwd   unknown                         /proc/1/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
init          1       root  rtd   unknown                         /proc/1/root
```

And the problem starts in col Device or Size/OFF but maybe in other situations could happen in all columns.

```
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
init          1       root  cwd       DIR                8,1      4096          2 /
init          1       root  rtd       DIR                8,1      4096          2 /
init          1       root  txt       REG                8,1     36992     139325 /sbin/init
init          1       root  mem       REG                8,1     14696     190970 /lib/libdl-2.11.3.so
init          1       root  mem       REG                8,1   1437064     190958 /lib/libc-2.11.3.so
python    30077     carlos    1u      CHR                1,3       0t0        700 /dev/null
```

Checking always is the same in the first row, the first column starts in C of COMMAND, second ends in D of PID, the four col. in D +1 of FD....
is there any way to count the number of spaces in the first row to use them to fill this code to parse the other rows?

```
# note: variable-length NAME field at the end intentionally omitted
base_format = '8s 1x 6s 1x 10s 1x 4s 1x 9s 1x 6s 1x 9s 1x 6s 1x'
base_format_size = struct.calcsize(base_format)
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: We could solve this pretty easily with a regex or split if there was a quick way to get lsof to put a character representing no data where it would put whitespace otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of reading on `lsof -F` after checking out the other thread and found that it does produce easily parsed output. Here's a quick demonstration of the general idea. It parses that and prints a small subset of the parsed output to show format. Are you able to use `-F` for your use case?

```
import subprocess
import copy
import pprint


def get_rows(output_to_parse, whitelist_keys):
    lines = output_to_parse.split("\n")
    rows = []
    while lines:
        row = _get_new_row(lines, whitelist_keys)
        rows.append(row)
    return rows


def _get_new_row(lines, whitelist_keys):
    new_row_keys = set()
    output = {}
    repeat = False
    while lines and repeat is False:
        line = lines.pop()
        if line == '':
            continue
        key = line[0]
        if key not in whitelist_keys:
            raise(ValueError(key))
        value = line[1:]
        if key not in new_row_keys:
            new_row_keys.add(key)
            output[key] = value
        else:
            repeat = True
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    identifiers = subprocess.Popen(["lsof", "-F", "?"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

    keys = set([line.strip()[0] for line in identifiers[1].split("\n") if line != ''][1:])

    lsof_output = subprocess.check_output(["lsof", "-F"])
    rows = get_rows(lsof_output, whitelist_keys=keys)
    pprint.pprint(rows[:20])
```

Comment: +1 for the `-F` idea. `lsof` may be slow. It might make sense to [parse its output incrementally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20386567/4279)

Answer (score 1):

As [@Tim Wilder said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20304501/4279), you could use `lsof -F` to get machine-readable output. Here's a script that converts `lsof` output into json. One json object per line. It produces output as soon as pipe buffers are full without waiting for the whole `lsof` process to end (it takes a while on my system):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import locale
from collections import OrderedDict
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(True) # for json

# define fields we are intersted in, see `lsof -F?`
# http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lsof/lsof-12/lsof/lsof_fields.h
ids = 'cpLftsn'
headers = 'COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE SIZE NAME'.split() # see lsof(8)
names = OrderedDict(zip(ids, headers)) # preserve order

# use '\0' byte as a field terminator and '\n' to separate each process/file set
p = Popen(["lsof", "-F{}0".format(''.join(names))], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
for line in p.stdout: # each line is a process or a file set
    #  id -> field
    fields = {f[:1].decode('ascii', 'strict'): f[1:].decode(encoding)
              for f in line.split(b'\0') if f.rstrip(b'\n')}
    if 'p' in fields: # process set
        process_info = fields # start new process set
    elif 'f' in fields: # file set
        fields.update(process_info) # add process info (they don't intersect)
        result = OrderedDict((name, fields.get(id))
                             for id, name in names.items())
        print(json.dumps(result)) # one object per line
    else:
        assert 0, 'either p or f ids should be present in a set'
p.communicate() # close stream, wait for the child to exit
```

The field names such as `COMMAND` are described in the [`lsof(8)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof#Output). To get the full list of available field ids, run `lsof -F?` or see [lsof_fields.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lsof/lsof-12/lsof/lsof_fields.h).

Fields that are not available are set to `null`. You could omit them instead. I've used `OrderedDict` to preserve order from run to run. `sorted_keys` parameter for `json.dumps` could be used instead. To pretty print, you could use `indent` parameter.

`lsof` converts non-printable (in current locale) characters using special encoding. It makes some values ambiguous.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you. It returns all data as if I just call lsof in contrast to another answer which returns much less data.