# fastest way to load a file in a known format into a dictionary with type casting

Tags: python

I am trying to load a file into a dictionary that comes in a very specific format. The format is a `>` character followed by a number on the first line, followed by a unique string on the second line. The number represents the number of times the string was seen.

As an example, one line pair may be

```
>5
ATGC
```

I need to load a very large file of this into a dictionary that maps the string to the value, as an int.

After some digging on SO, the fastest way I have found so far is:

```
from itertools import izip

with open(args.sample_counts) as f:
    data_counts = {seq.rstrip() : int(count.rstrip().lstrip(">")) for count, seq in izip(*[f]*2)}
```

Which takes about 2 hours on a 315gb data file. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this even faster?

Comment: It may load faster if you split the file by the number of cores you have and use multiprocessing to load and process.  That way you parallelize much of the work.

Comment: How does this compare with just *reading* a 315gb file?

Comment: I would look towards things like spark or ipython which have some built in level of parallelism.

Comment: "315gb data file"? Do you have 315 GB of RAM?  When I've worked with supercomputers, I've always used C and other "fast" languages.  Using Python for this seems odd.

Comment: The `count.rstrip().lstrip(">")` is unnecessary, just use `count[1:]`.

Comment: If the fields `count` and `seq` are of a fixed length, you could use [Efficient way of parsing fixed width files in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4915359/355230).