# Can I use dictReader to ingest the output of lsof and ps?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

The standard Unix utilities like [`lsof`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) and [`ps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) produce output in a fixed width format with a header which should be easy to ingest programmatically.

Alas, the existing answers to [How to efficiently parse fixed width files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4914008/850781) require me to specify the column widths in advance instead of inferring then from the header line.

So, what is the right way to ingest the output of `ps` and `lsof` (and their ilk) into Python?

Comment: Don't look to parsing output from system utilities if [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) covers what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I used until I switched to [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil):

```
import subprocess

def lsof ():
    with subprocess.popen(["lsof"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as fd:
        header = fd.readline().split()
        for line in fdout:
            return [dict(zip(header,line.split())) for line in fd]
```

**Warning**: this ignores the possibility of spaces in the `lsof` output fields!