# splitting the line into multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

below is the text that i want to split and store it in the variables.

```
Pppp CCCC TTTT                           MMMMM            SSSSSS Oono.   

1  NIL fL-E 10UU (SPD+), 1000XXXXX (SPD) WEEEEEEEEEEEEE   CATTTTTTTTT   
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
```

i want to split it so that 
variable 1 :-

```
 Pppp

 1    
 44    
 44    
 44   
 44
 44
```

Variable 2 :-

```
CCCC TTTT                              

NIL fL-E 10UU (SPD+), 1000XXXXX (SPD)    
10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS 
10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS 
10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS 
10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS 
10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS
```

Variable 3:-

```
MMMMM            

 WEEEEEEEEEEEEE      
 WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I 
 WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I 
 WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I 
 WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I 
 WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I
```

Variable 4:-

```
SSSSSS Oono.

CATTTTTTTTT
CATTTTTTTTT
CATTTTTTTTT
CATTTTTTTTT
CATTTTTTTTT
CATTTTTTTTT
```

Each variable should store specified value

code i have tried:-

```
with open ('sh_module.txt', 'r') as module_info:
    lines = module_info.read().splitlines()[6:]
    for l in lines:
        if not l.isspace():
            storeSplit = ("  ".join(l.split()[1:10]))
            A_of_splitOfstoreSplit , B_of_splitOfstoreSplit = storeSplit.split('W') 
            print (storeSplit)
```

code doesn't works. :-(

Note:- the text so written is as it is in the text file. do consider the spaces.!

thx for the help.! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently parse fixed width files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/how-to-efficiently-parse-fixed-width-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: found [How to efficiently parse fixed width files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/how-to-efficiently-parse-fixed-width-files) after answering. This answer is specific to your question, the dupe shows other ways to deal with fixed length file parsing using structs etc.

---

You seem to have a fixed-width format - you can simply split each line into a list and then transpose it into colums using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

**Create file:**

```
# 3456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
t = """
Pppp CCCC TTTT                           MMMMM            SSSSSS Oono.   

1  NIL fL-E 10UU (SPD+), 1000XXXXX (SPD) WEEEEEEEEEEEEE   CATTTTTTTTT   
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT 
"""

with open ('sh_module.txt', 'w') as module_info:
    module_info.write("header\nheader\nheader\nheader\nheader\nheader\n")
    module_info.write(t)
```

**Process file:**

```
with open ('sh_module.txt', 'r') as module_info:
    lines = [n.strip() for n in module_info.read().splitlines()[6:]]


data = [] 

# split file-lines into data - special case for line starting with Pppp as its 4 long
for line in lines:
    # ignore empty lines
    if line.strip():
        if line.startswith("Pppp"):  # slightly different fixed width
            data.append( [line[:4].strip(), line[4:41].strip(), 
                          line[41:58].strip(),line[58:].strip()] )
            continue
        linedata = []
        linedata.extend( (line[:3].strip(), line[3:41].strip(), 
                          line[41:58].strip(),line[58:].strip()) )
        data.append(linedata)

# create a dict with variables from the splitted line-list
variabs = {a[0]:[i for i in a[1:]] for a in zip(*data)}

print(variabs)
```

Output:

```
{'Pppp': ['1', '44', '44', '44', '44', '44'],
 'CCCC TTTT': ['NIL fL-E 10UU (SPD+), 1000XXXXX (SPD)', '10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS', 
               '10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS', '10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS', 
               '10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS', '10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS'], 
 'MMMMM': ['WEEEEEEEEEEEEE', 'WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I', 'WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I', 'WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I', 
           'WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I', 'WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I'], 
 'SSSSSS Oono.': ['CATTTTTTTTT', 'CATTTTTTTTT', 'CATTTTTTTTT', 'CATTTTTTTTT', 'CATTTTTTTTT', 
                  'CATTTTTTTTT']}
```

You can access the columns by `variabs["Pppp"]`, `variabs["SSSSSS Oono."]`, etc.

---

There are other ways to handle this, see [How to efficiently parse fixed width files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/how-to-efficiently-parse-fixed-width-files) for more

---

Edit: using enumerate:

```
# split file-lines into data - special case for line on idx 0  
for idx, line in enumerate(x.strip() for x in lines if x.strip()):
    if idx == 0:  # slightly different fixed width
        data.append( [line[:4].strip(), line[4:41].strip(), 
                      line[41:58].strip(),line[58:].strip()] )
        continue
    linedata = []
    linedata.extend( (line[:3].strip(), line[3:41].strip(), 
                      line[41:58].strip(),line[58:].strip()) )
    data.append(linedata)
```

Comment: i understood ur code and your code worked.! but can u please explain the line **variabs = {a[0]:[i for i in a[1:]] for a in zip(*data)}** . a bit in detail if u can.!

Comment: @Mystery it is a dictionary comprehension that is used to create the column view frop the zip(*data) values. Essentially `data` is a list of lists - each inner list is one line. Using `zip(*data)` creates a generator of tuples where the first tuple consists of all 0-elements of all inner lists, the next tuple contains all 1-element of all inner lists etc. You can use `for a in zip(*data): print(a)` to print the tuples. `variabs = {a[0]:[i for i in a[1:]] for a in zip(*data)}` just creates the dictionary with the first value of the tuple as key and the other of the tuple as value.

Comment: what if the keys varies, that is, as of now i m accessing the lists using the keys **"Pppp"** but how about keeping the keys as a variable that takes in the dynamic content so produced.? how can i achieve that.?

Comment: what if **Pppp** in the code is not there, instead it's "6" or something else.? to be specific i want to keep the keys,**variable**, that is, it could be anything.

Comment: @Mystery I have no idea what you are after. To use "dynamically" named variables you use a dictionary. If your 1st line is always the one with the key names, use `for idx, line in enumerate(lines):` and on idx==0 extract the keys and on all other idx split by positional slicing. This solution should be enough to start you to a solution that fits towards your undisclosed other data. see edit. I have no idea how you want to address your "variables" then - if you do not kow their names.

Comment: can we initiate a conversation in chat ?

Comment: @Mystery https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197318/python-fixed-csv-splitting-the-line-into-multiple-variables