# Read a text file with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a text file with two million rows:

```
adsh    tag version coreg   ddate   qtrs    uom value   footnote
0001065088-20-000018    DecreaseInUnrecognizedTaxBenefitsIsReasonablyPossible   us-gaap/2018        20200331    0   USD 19000000.0000   
0000885725-20-000022    DecreaseInUnrecognizedTaxBenefitsIsReasonablyPossible   us-gaap/2018        20200331    0   USD 98000000.0000   
0000837465-20-000010    DecreaseInUnrecognizedTaxBenefitsIsReasonablyPossible   us-gaap/2018        20200331    0   USD 449000.0000 
0001730168-20-000109    DecreaseInUnrecognizedTaxBenefitsIsReasonablyPossible   us-gaap/2018        20200430    0   USD 154000000.0000  
0001730168-20-000109    OperatingLeasesRentExpenseNet   us-gaap/2018        20190430    1   USD 59000000.0000   
0001730168-20-000109    OperatingLeasesRentExpenseNet   us-gaap/2018        20190430    2   USD 126000000.0000  
0001104659-20-068703    OperatingLeasesRentExpenseNet   us-gaap/2018        20180131    4   USD 19700000.0000
0001418135-20-000018    OtherAmortizationOfDeferredCharges  us-gaap/2018        20190331    1   USD 36000000.0000   Primarily includes amortization of customer rebates and upfront payments.
0001002910-20-000115    OtherAmortizationOfDeferredCharges  us-gaap/2018    UnionElectricCompany    20200331    1   USD 23000000.0000
```

You can see that this text file has 9 columns and, in the first rows there are only 7 columns. This is because there are other rows with 9 columns. I need to write a MySQL database with every row but I have to take into account the `NULL`values like this:

```
adsh                    tag                                                     version       coreg                  ddate      qtrs    uom  value          footnote
0001065088-20-000018    DecreaseInUnrecognizedTaxBenefitsIsReasonablyPossible   us-gaap/2018   NULL                  20200331   0       USD  19000000.0000  NULL
0001002910-20-000115    OtherAmortizationOfDeferredCharges                      us-gaap/2018   UnionElectricCompany  20200331   1       USD  23000000.0000  NULL
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Well, the target table should have the corresponding columns nullable.

Comment: Yes. But when I convert the line into a string list and insert it in MySQL every cell is inserted sequentially. Column1, first cell, column2, second cell, and so on. I always get the last cells NULL which actually they are not, as you can see in the example text file.

Comment: Well, you need to decompose your problem into parsing and inserting. You need to ensure you are correctly reading row by row ensuring you are getting nulls at the correct position.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/how-to-efficiently-parse-fixed-width-files

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Why do (most) question askers think that anyone is *impressed* when they start their question with "a text file with two million rows"...?

Answer (score 0):

with open ("filename.txt", 'r') as nametxt;
Text = (nametext (read());
Print (Text)

Something like that