# Convert list of strings to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a list that looks like this:

```
Sum = ['* Report_type         Leach\n',
       '* Result_text         Concentration \n',
       '* Run_Id              179\n',
       '* Location            MUENSTER\n',
       '* Meteo_station       KREM-M\n',
       '* Soil_type           KREM\n',
       '* Crop_calendar       SUGARBEET\n',
       '* Substance           ABC\n',
       '* Application_scheme  DRY\n',
       '* Deposition_scheme   No\n',
       '* Results             0.0001\n'
       ]
```

and I want to convert it to a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df =    
        col1                col2
0       Report_type         Leach          
1       Result_text         Concentration
2       Run_Id              179                
3       Location            MUENSTER      
4       Meteo_station       KREM-M             
5       Soil_type           KREM       
6       Crop_calendar       SUGARBEET     
7       Substance           ABC                
8       Application_scheme  DRY                
9       Deposition_scheme   No                 
10      Results             0.0001
```

The first columns of characters in the list has a fixed lenght.

Comment: Here's a StackOverflow post on parsing fixed-width fields with Python.  The original post specifically mentioned fixed-length:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/how-to-efficiently-parse-fixed-width-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(maxsplit=2)[1:] for i in Sum],columns=['col1','col2'])
```

**Output:**

```
                  col1           col2
0          Report_type          Leach
1          Result_text  Concentration
2               Run_Id            179
3             Location       MUENSTER
4        Meteo_station         KREM-M
5            Soil_type           KREM
6        Crop_calendar      SUGARBEET
7            Substance            ABC
8   Application_scheme            DRY
9    Deposition_scheme             No
10             Results         0.0001
```

Comment: Great solution but what if there are more than one word in column two? Like instead of "Concentration" it was " Concentration of Water". Then it will split at each blank spaces and creates two more columns.

Comment: Hey @Bob, edited my answer so it splits a maximum of two times, thus keeping the whole phrase in column two if it has more than one word

Answer (score 1):

Using `str` methods

**Ex:**

```
data = ['* Report_type         Leach\n',
       '* Result_text         Concentration \n',
       '* Run_Id              179\n',
       '* Location            MUENSTER\n',
       '* Meteo_station       KREM-M\n',
       '* Soil_type           KREM\n',
       '* Crop_calendar       SUGARBEET\n',
       '* Substance           ABC\n',
       '* Application_scheme  DRY\n',
       '* Deposition_scheme   No\n',
       '* Results             0.0001\n'
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": data})
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df.pop('Col').str.strip(" * ").str.split(expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                  col1           col2
0          Report_type          Leach
1          Result_text  Concentration
2               Run_Id            179
3             Location       MUENSTER
4        Meteo_station         KREM-M
5            Soil_type           KREM
6        Crop_calendar      SUGARBEET
7            Substance            ABC
8   Application_scheme            DRY
9    Deposition_scheme             No
10             Results         0.0001
```