# How to read the table from this webpage using python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

webpage link - http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/stars.html

I tried using pandas read_html and web scraping libraries like bs4 but no luck as the data on the webpage is not wrapped inside a table tag.
Please help me out!

Comment: this is known as a fixed width delimited file, you may find it easiest to import into google sheets / excel and then save as a csv

Comment: then after that you can use the pandas result here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23354484/5125264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the data is contained in the `<pre>`
- create DF using [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)
- *infer* does a reasonable job,  if the rest is important you can specify the column widths

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/stars.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser",)
txt = soup.find("pre").getText()

# fixed format,  infer the columns
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(txt), infer_nrows=300)

# just rows that have a number in first columns
dfd = df[df["1"].str.match("^[0-9][0-9]*\.$").fillna(False)]
dfd.head(10)

dfd.head(10)
```

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 5 | 6 7 | 8 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | Alpha Canis Majoris | Sirius | 06 45 -16.7 | 227.2 -8.9 | A1V -1.46 | 1.43 | 379.21 | 1.58 | 9 |
| 4 | 2 | Alpha Carinae | Canopus | 06 24 -52.7 | 261.2 -25.3 | F0Ib -0.73 | -5.64 | 10.43 | 0.53 | 310 |
| 5 | 3 | Alpha Centauri | Rigil Kentaurus | 14 40 -60.8 | 315.8 -0.7 | G2V+K1V -0.29 | 4.06 | 742.12 | 1.4 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | Alpha Boötis | Arcturus | 14 16 +19.2 | 15.2 +69.0 | K2III -0.05 | -0.31 | 88.85 | 0.74 | 37 |
| 7 | 5 | Alpha Lyrae | Vega | 18 37 +38.8 | 67.5 +19.2 | A0V 0.03 | 0.58 | 128.93 | 0.55 | 25 |
| 8 | 6 | Alpha Aurigae | Capella | 05 17 +46.0 | 162.6 +4.6 | G5III+G0III 0.07 | -0.49 | 77.29 | 0.89 | 42 |
| 9 | 7 | Beta Orionis | Rigel | 05 15 -8.2 | 209.3 -25.1 | B8Ia 0.15v | -6.72v | 4.22 | 0.81 | 770 |
| 10 | 8 | Alpha Canis Minoris | Procyon | 07 39 +5.2 | 213.7 +13.0 | F5IV-V 0.36 | 2.64 | 285.93 | 0.88 | 11 |
| 11 | 9 | Alpha Eridani | Achernar | 01 38 -57.2 | 290.7 -58.8 | B3V 0.45 | -2.77 | 22.68 | 0.57 | 144 |
| 12 | 10 | Alpha Orionis | Betelgeuse | 05 55 +7.4 | 199.8 -9.0 | M2Ib 0.55v | -5.04v | 7.63 | 1.64 | 430 |

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

- copy the table (spaces and everything!)
- use text editor to get column width delimters
- read in using pandas

Note I have used a truncated data set here because of character limits:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
  1. Alpha Canis Majoris       Sirius            06 45 -16.7  227.2  -8.9  A1V          -1.46   1.43  379.21 1.58     9
  2. Alpha Carinae             Canopus           06 24 -52.7  261.2 -25.3  F0Ib         -0.73  -5.64   10.43 0.53   310
  3. Alpha Centauri            Rigil Kentaurus   14 40 -60.8  315.8  -0.7  G2V+K1V      -0.29   4.06  742.12 1.40     4
  4. Alpha Boötis              Arcturus          14 16 +19.2   15.2 +69.0  K2III        -0.05  -0.31   88.85 0.74    37
  5. Alpha Lyrae               Vega              18 37 +38.8   67.5 +19.2  A0V           0.03   0.58  128.93 0.55    25
  6. Alpha Aurigae             Capella           05 17 +46.0  162.6  +4.6  G5III+G0III   0.07  -0.49   77.29 0.89    42
  7. Beta Orionis              Rigel             05 15  -8.2  209.3 -25.1  B8Ia          0.15v -6.72v   4.22 0.81   770
  8. Alpha Canis Minoris       Procyon           07 39  +5.2  213.7 +13.0  F5IV-V        0.36   2.64  285.93 0.88    11
  9. Alpha Eridani             Achernar          01 38 -57.2  290.7 -58.8  B3V           0.45  -2.77   22.68 0.57   144
 10. Alpha Orionis             Betelgeuse        05 55  +7.4  199.8  -9.0  M2Ib          0.55v -5.04v   7.63 1.64   430
"""

# Using Pandas with a column specification
col_specification = [(0, 5),
 (5, 31),
 (31, 50),
 (50, 53),
 (53, 56),
 (56, 63),
 (63, 68),
 (68, 74),
 (74, 79),
 (79, 94),
 (94, 101),
 (101, 109),
 (109, 106),
 (106, 114),
 (114, 120)]

data = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(data), colspecs=col_specification)

data
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how you'd figure out those tuple values for the colspecs?