# Python regex to find connected digits

Tags: python, regex

I have raw txt files and need to use regex to search each digit separated by space.

Question, data format is like:

```
   6   3   1   0
   7   3   1   0
   8   35002   0
   9   34104   0
```

My regex is:

```
(?P<COORD>\d+)
```

The matched output for first two lines are, (6,3,1,0) and (7,3,1,0) which are correct.
However, it doesn't apply to last two lines, their output are (8, 35002, 0) and (9, 34104, 0). The correct grouping numbers should be (8, 3, 5002, 0) and (9, 3, 4104, 0). How can I solve this?

Comment: This is a fixed-width text, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/how-to-efficiently-parse-fixed-width-files

Comment: [`(?P<COORD>(?<= {4})|(?<= {3})\d|(?<= {2})\d{2}|(?<= )\d{3}|\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/1sgwM4/1)

Comment: @horcrux This code works. How can I rename these 4 groups of digits in different name?

Comment: `my_regex = "".join([r" *(?P<COORD%s>(?<= {4})|(?<= {3})\d|(?<= {2})\d{2}|(?<= )\d{3}|\d{4})" % i for i in range(1,5)])` gives you [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/AiWgZO/1)

Comment: @horcrux thank you! I wish I can give you the best answer if you don't mind adding an answer

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are aligned and the width of the columns are fixed,
You can use

```
width = 4
for line in lines:
    columns = [ line[j: j + width] for j in range(0, len(line), width)]
    numbers = list(map(lambda x: int(x.strip()), columns))
    # or a one liner
    print(list(int(line[j:j+width].strip()) for j in range(0, len(line), width)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to use regex? Because I have other lines in string.