# Parse flat-file (positional text-file) to read a column

Tags: python

I have this code:
the data is: element, ion, wavelength, data1, abundance.

```
txt='FI R       83.0000m   34.960    1.1262      Fe 2      1.32055m   33.626    0.0522      
N  2      5754.61A   33.290    0.0241
TI R       1800.00m   33.092    0.0153      Fe 2      1.24854m   32.645    0.0054      N  
2      915.612A   31.997    0.0012
NI Ra      2.85000m   36.291   24.1132      Fe 2      7637.54A   33.077    0.0147      N  
2      2139.01A   32.920    0.0103
NI Rb      3.00000m   35.765    7.1930      Fe 2      4889.62A   32.774    0.0073      N  
2      1084.58A   31.927    0.0010'

N2=re.findall('N  2.*?([0-9].*?)\s', text)

for value in N2:
    del_letters = re.sub('[A-Za-z]', '', value)
    float_value = float(del_letters)
    if (float_value >= 5700) and (float_value <=5800):
        print(value)
```

But this only gives me the third column, and i want to obtain the value of the 5 column which is 0.0241, i tried but i can't resolve

Comment: Is this a [fixed width string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914008/how-to-efficiently-parse-fixed-width-files)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: At the end i worte, i want to obtain the value of the column five, taking in consideration the valur of the wavelength that i wrote in the if, the value that i want is 0.0241

Comment: @kmoser This isn't CSV data. There are no files

Comment: No, the other links aren't the same question.  This data is not CSV.  There is a question on fixed width files but it is all about NOT using slicing and looking for alternatives like the struct module which is mostly not appropriate for this task — struct is primarily for binary data.

Answer (score 1):

[String slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) can help extract the data.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
for r in txt.splitlines():
    fields = r[:2], r[3], float(r[6:18]), float(r[20:28])
    print(fields)
```

This outputs:

```
('FI', 'R', 83.0, 34.96)
('TI', 'R', 1800.0, 33.092)
('NI', 'R', 2.85, 36.291)
('NI', 'R', 3.0, 35.765)
```

Comment: But this only read the left column, and I want both

Comment: @JoanLopez What do you mean "both"? As written, this is to "get you started". You'll need to count the characters out until you get to the position of each line that has the data you're looking for